# Rotate diamond symbol

Tags: circuitikz

How can I turn the diamond symbol 90 degrees?

I tried the following code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[float=false, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{bipoles/buffer/height/.initial=0.8}
\ctikzset{bipoles/buffer/width/.initial=0.9}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}

    \path (0,0) coordinate (GND) ;

    \draw  [<-,>=diamond] (GND)
           (GND) node[left]{$IBGND$} 
           ;  
 \end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

In the code given in question, only coordinate `(gnd)` was mentioned. It was not a path. Mention the path properly. Node labeling also can be done in the same line.

```
\draw  [<-,>=diamond] (GND)node[left]{$IBGND$}--++(1,0);
```

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[float=false, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{bipoles/buffer/height/.initial=0.8,
          bipoles/buffer/width/.initial=0.9}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \path (0,0) coordinate (GND) ;
    \draw  [<-,>=diamond] (GND)node[left]{$IBGND$}--++(1,0);
 \end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```